# Angular highcharts - reset zoom manually

Tags: angularjs, highcharts-ng

I am using `highcharts-ng`, how can i reset manually using reset button?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle.

Comment: Which reset button you are reffering to?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/8r3gdwqt/1/]
I just figured it out. Here is the fiddle for it. But I'm still struggling hide the original reset button.